# Access 2010 Query pulling data that matches a label value

Tags: ms-access, label

I have a system where a lecturer logs on, when he logs on his username value is put through to a label on the next page, from there, he will be able to view two columns of information, and only if the column on the right's value is the same as whats in the label.

Is it possible to pull this value from a textbox or something I can store on this page?

Would this almost be possible?

```
SELECT [moduleID], [lecturerID] FROM [Teaching] WHERE [lecturerID] = label1.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You will need to reference the form name that contains the control where the ID is stored. Something like the following should work:

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTable.LectureID=[Forms].[Form1].[txtID]
```

I would probably put the LectureID into a text box instead of a label and either lock the control so it can't be edited or make the control invisible so the user doesn't see it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim, does it matter that i am calling it from a grid view?

Comment: I don't think it should. You can make the query that the grid is bound to reference the control on the form where the user's id is stored.